# Why mishandled error message when Unicode is inside elif statement?

Tags: python, error-handling

As an exemple if you run this code:

```
text = "Hi"

if text == "Hello":
    print("Hello")
elif text == "Hi":
    emoji = '\U000274C'
    print(emoji)
else: 
    print("")
```

You will get

> "IndentationError: unexpected indent"

as a erro message, but if you run just `emoji = '\U000274C'` you will get the correct erro

> "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 0-8: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Any ideas why? is it a bug or a feature and why?
The correct message is really useful as it makes clear that you forgot a zero in thhe unicode, while the indentation erro is totally useless.

I was expecting a useful erro message, it's not clear to me if this behavior is correct or if it is a bug.

Comment: Can't reproduce the indent error. https://ideone.com/yRWLsP. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Me neither.  Running the whole of the code in the question gives me "SyntaxError (unicode error)...", not an indentation error.

Comment: Mixing spaces and tabs, perhaps?  Tabs are treated as 8 spaces, even if they are visually displayed as 4.  Show the full stack trace and that should indicate the line of the error.

Comment: And if you think Python has a bug, a good bet is no, it's your code that has the error.

Comment: Whatever indentation error you have, it's found by the parser *before* it tries to parse `'\U000274c'`. Once you find one syntax error, anything after it is assumed unparseable and the parser won't even look at it.

Comment: The indentation error is unrelated to the invalid string literal, not just the same error reported differently.

Comment: There are two unrelated problems here, both arguably typos - but the first one has a canonical Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not write emoji unicode correctly.
It usually have 8 digits. You only wrote 7 digits, so check this part.

I slightly modified your 'elif' part with a popular example unicode. Unicode and CDLR-name both work and return . It works even on Online-Python-Compiler.
Another try with '\U0000274C', which seems most similar to your unicode, returned ❌.

```
text = "Hi"
if text == "Hello":
    print("Hello")
elif text == "Hi":
    emoji = "\U0001f600"
    # emoji = "\N{grinning face}"
    print(emoji)
else: 
    print("")
```